# Can I call a .pl file from a module in perl?

Tags: perl, module

I have created a Perl module from a `.pl` file and I am testing it at the moment. It works until the point where it needs to use another `.pl` file (to pull out some sql statements). I am calling the file using `require 'file.pl';`. This is a temporary solution as the `.pl` file will be replaced in the future by a better database solution, but for now I need to test my module code. It doesn't like trying to find the file, though, even though I have put the path name in `@INC` using `use lib '/path/to/file'`.

Is there any temporary solution I can use to solve this problem? I don't know when the `.pl` file will be replaced, so I can't rely on waiting for that. Should I just move the sql statements into the `.pm` file even though I will have to remove them later, or do I have to search out the folder that the module is in the put a copy of the `.pl` file in it?

Comment: Note, `.pl` is usually used for files with `package`, in which case you shouldn't be using `require` at all. You should be using `do '/path/to/file.pl;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can require the full pathname:

```
require '/path/to/file.pl';
```

Comment: this makes sense and I should have thought to put this before, but it still thinks the method I'm calling from the `.pl` file is part of my module. Is there anyway to specify where the subroutine is? (like how you can do `use Module qw(sub_name)`)

Comment: oooh think I've sorted this, I had the file in a package - removed that line and hey, presto! thanks :)